# Combination of an string array in c# without repetition

Tags: c#, .net

I am new to c# and I need to perform a permutation without repetition for the arrays.
For example, Below are the 2 string arrays.

```
string[] str1 = String[]{"E1","E2","E3"};
string[] str2 = String[]{"E1","E2","E3","E4"};
```

And I need to generate output for str1 as

```
{"E1","E2","E3","E1 E2","E1 E3","E2 E3","E1 E2 E3"}
```

and for str2 as

```
{"E1","E2","E3","E4","E1 E2","E1 E3","E1 E4","E2 E3","E2 E4",
 "E3 E4","E1 E2 E3","E1 E2 E4","E1 E3 E4","E2 E3 E4","E1 E2 E3 E4"}`
```

Also, I would like to compare the output of str1 & str2. If any of the results are matching(ex.:`E2 E3`& `E2 E3`) then I need to return "Output is matching" but I am stuck on how to proceed with the below coding in c# and the output is repeating and also array length is static. Please guide me.

```
String[] str1 = { "E1", "E2", "E3" };

List<string> resultedValue = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < str1.Length; i++)
 {
  for (int j = 0; j < str1.Length; j++)
   {
     if (i == j) resultedValue.Add(string.Format("[ {0} ]", str1[i]));
     else resultedValue.Add(string.Format("[ {0} {1} ]", str1[i], str1[j]));
   }
 }
 Console.WriteLine(resultedValue.ToArray());
```

Comment: Can you describe the permutation algorithm in pseudocode?

Comment: In other words: please show us your attempt first, then we can help you fix it

Comment: @SamAxe Then it should be easy to find a duplicate...

Comment: What you want is all the combinations of all lengths.  Check out this blog by Eric Lippert that goes over how to create combinations of one length https://ericlippert.com/2014/10/13/producing-combinations-part-one/

Comment: FYI this is not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5128615/c-sharp-string-permutation as the OP has mistakenly used the term permutations, but they actually want combinations.

Comment: I have added the code which I am not able to proceed, not able to expand the array dynamically.

Comment: You can make a block of code by using three ticks on a new line before and after your block of code. This will make it a lot easier to see what your code is meant to look like.

Comment: Done with a block of code

Comment: Do you need to sort `str1` and `str2` or does the order matter (they will create different combination strings)? Also your code isn't valid.

Comment: Order doesn't matter

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7802892/3034273) should help. The solution is very elegant when you realize how it works.

Comment: Thanks, Xerillio. This helps me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't remember where I got this code (possibly translated from another language), and it isn't very efficient, but it also isn't length constrained, but using LINQ, you can get the powerset of an `IEnumerable`, minus the empty set:

```
public static class IEnumerableExt {
    public static string Join(this IEnumerable<string> src, string sep) => String.Join(sep, src);

    public static bool IsEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> src) => !src.Any();

    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> AllCombinations<T>(this IEnumerable<T> start) {
        IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> HelperCombinations(IEnumerable<T> items) {
            if (items.IsEmpty())
                yield return items;
            else {
                var head = items.First();
                var tail = items.Skip(1);
                foreach (var sequence in HelperCombinations(tail)) {
                    yield return sequence; // Without first
                    yield return sequence.Prepend(head);
                }
            }
        }

        return HelperCombinations(start).Skip(1); // don't return the empty set
    }
}
```

With these extension methods, you can do:

```
var comboStr1 = str1.AllCombinations().Select(ss => ss.Join(" "));
var comboStr2 = str2.AllCombinations().Select(ss => ss.Join(" "));

var hsComboStr1 = comboStr1.ToHashSet();
var ans = comboStr2.Any(s2combo => hsComboStr1.Contains(s2combo));
```

to determine if the powersets of `str1` and `str2` share any members.